# Convert time in react big calendar from 0000000 to 0z

Tags: reactjs, date, react-big-calendar

Hi I am currently facing the problem in react where I use react-big-calendar. The time is off by one hour, likely caused because daylight savings and timezone differences.

My code looks like the following:

The part where I struggle is to convert the date in my data object to isoISO 8601. I am unable to parse start and end properties from microsoftgraph Event and any guidance would be appreciated very much!

Note that currently what date I get returned from my event start and end is "2022-11-16T07:30:00.0000000" but I want to convert it to "2022-11-16T07:30:00.0z", if that makes sense.

```
   const data = calendarEvent.map((event: microsoftgraph.Event) => {
        return {
            id: event.id,
            title: event.location.displayName,
            allDay: false,
            start: new Date(event.start.dateTime), 
            end: new Date(event.end.dateTime),
        }
    });
```

EDIT: Solution was to add a string `"z"` after `event.start.dateTime`
It's not the most elegant solution but it works, for now.

Code with the solution implemented:

```
   const data = calendarEvent.map((event: microsoftgraph.Event) => {
        return {
            id: event.id,
            title: event.location.displayName,
            allDay: false,
            start: new Date(event.start.dateTime + "z"), 
            end: new Date(event.end.dateTime + "z"),
        }
    });
```

Comment: The date *string* already is in ISO8601 format. There's nothing to "convert". The `Date` object itself has no format. How its's displayed is a styling issue

Comment: Maybe I worded my problem improperly. But as stated above I currently get a time that is one hour behind my local time. And what event.start.date.time returns is 07:30 instead of 08:30. Aka it currently returns "16T07:30:00.0000000" (07:30) but I want it to convert it to "2022-11-16T07:30:00.0z", which is 08:30 (my local time).

Comment: `which is 08:30 (my local time).` it's not. It's 7:30 UTC, nothing more. Both *strings* are the same ISO8601 date and time value, except the first is ambiguous, the second specifies it's UTC. You could append `Z` to the original string before parsing it with `new Date()`. In any case, the code you posted uses `Date` which has no format. Internally [it's a count of milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#description) since 1970-01-01.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question, or I am simply just not wording it correct, the time that gets output is not correct and is one hour behind. The reason why is because of the z (zero) is not included in what it currently returns. Oh well, guess I am on my own here.

Comment: What is `event.start.dateTime`? A `Date` or a string? I suspect the real question is either how to treat `Date` as UTC or parse a string as UTC. `new Date('2022-11-16T07:30:00.0000000Z')` works, so if you know that `dateTime` is a string, you can just append `Z` to it.

Comment: `I am on my own here.` no, because hundreds of thousands of developers use JavaScript Date and ISO8601. What you ask has been asked and solved by **every Javascript developer**, including British devs - in summer they use DST too. And Yes, JS is *bad* at dates, which is why `moment.js` and such libraries exist

Comment: new Date("2022-11-16T07:30:00.0z") 08:30 this is what I am trying to do. Instead of new Date("2022-11-16T07:30:00.00")

Comment: First, why is `dateTime` a string instead of `Date`? It's better to parse the string into a `Date` when parsing the response, when you know what the offset is. If you can't do that, and you're sure the time is always UTC, you can just append `Z`. It's dirty but it works. If you have to convert between offsets, you probably a library because JS itself is very bad at this. There's no built-in `Date` method to convert between offsets

Comment: `this is what I am trying to do.` there's no such thing. Z means UTC. `2022-11-16T07:30:00.0z` means 7:30 UTC. Period. That **UTC** time will be displayed by *the browser* in either UTC or localized form. That's a matter of styling. It's the *browser* that decides what offset to add to the UTC time.

Comment: On my machine for example `new Date("2022-11-16T07:30:00.0z")` returns `Wed Nov 16 2022 09:30:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`. Not 8:30. So does `new Date('2022-11-16T07:30:00.0000000Z')`. I actually tested this before posting

Comment: What does `new Date('2022-11-16T07:30:00.0000000Z')` display on *your* machine? Open your browser's Developer Tools and try it in the Console

Comment: It returns ```Wed Nov 16 2022 08:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)```

Comment: Besides, the [react-big-calendar date formatting docs](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar#localization-and-date-formatting) show you *need* a date library if you want to display time in a local format. `You must choose a localizer to use this library`

Comment: Of course, I know, I've followed the documentation on their site. I use moment js library

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I know it's a bit hard to undertand the code when you don't have the context in full and the rest of the code. I'm not that familiar with date formatting in js or just date in general . I've managed to fix it by adding a ```"z"``` after ``` event.start.dateTime```. So the solution was ```                                             start: new Date(event.start.dateTime + "z"), end: new Date(event.end.dateTime + "z"), ```

Comment: If you already use a date library, use it to parse the string as well. For example, `moment.utc('2022-11-16T07:30:00.0000000').toDate()` will parse the string as UTC even if it has no offset specifier. `toDate()` will return a JavaScript `Date`. It's unusual that MS Graph returns a UTC date without `Z`. That *could* change in the future (although it's unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

The date string is already in ISO-8601 form but has no offset indicator. `new Date(string)` will parse it assuming it's local to the browser's timezone. On my machine, omitting the offset results in a `+02:00` offset:

```
> new Date('2022-11-16T07:30:00.0000000')
<- Wed Nov 16 2022 07:30:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
> new Date('2022-11-16T07:30:00.0000000Z')
<- Wed Nov 16 2022 09:30:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
> new Date('2022-11-16T07:30:00.0000000+04:00')
<- Wed Nov 16 2022 05:30:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```

A dirty hack would be to just append `Z` to the date string. This will work as long as `dateTime` has no offset or timezone indicator:

```
start: new Date(event.start.dateTime + 'Z')
```

Another option is to use the date library used with `react-big-calendar` to parse ambiguous date strings as UTC :

```
start: moment.utc(event.start.dateTime)
```

**`event` and Timezones**

Unfortunately, the [dateTimeZone.dateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0) field is UTC by default but *can* refer to a different time zone. This is specified in the `dateTimeZone.timeZone` field. If there's a chance that MS Graph returns local times, the `field` property should be checked.

If MS Graph returns an IANA timezone the [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) package can be used to parse both the time and timezone name :

```
start: moment.utc(event.start.dateTime,event.start.timeZone)
```

The following call returns `08:30` on my browser's console:

```
> moment.tz('2022-11-16T07:30:00.0000000','Europe/Vienna').toDate()
<- Wed Nov 16 2022 08:30:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```